# Length of a decreasing infinite interval?

Tags: measure-theory

This is from Wikipedia under Measure:
For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $E_n=[n,\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then the intersection of all $E_n$ is empty. However, the Lebesgue measure for all of these sets is infinite.

Help me understand this: Why doesn't the length of the interval tend to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: It cannot tend to zero as $\mu(E_n)$ is always greater than a lot of things, including any positive constant $c$ since $[n, n+c] \subset [n, \infty)$, or any positive function of $n$  since $[n, n+f(n)] \subset [n, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to tend to 0,  we would need the following:  For any $\epsilon>0$,  there exists a $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge N$  $\mu (E_n)<\epsilon$ where $\mu()$ is lebesgue measure.

However, this is never true since for any given n,  $\mu (E_n)=\infty>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to consider the measure of each $E_n$ as a (extended) real number and then think only of the sequence.

For this example, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, $\mu(E_1) = \infty$, $\mu(E_2) = \infty$, and so on.  Thus the sequence can be written 
$$ (\mu(E_n))_{n\geq 1} = (\mu(E_1), \mu(E_2), \dots) = (\infty, \infty, \infty, \dots). $$
A sequence where every term is $\infty$ of course converges to $\infty$, not $0$.

On the other hand, $\mu(\lim E_n) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$, so the oddity here is that 
$\lim \mu(E_n) = \infty \neq 0 = \mu(\lim E_n)$.  I.e. the limit and measure do not commute.